# How to select element that meets exactly n times?

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
+-----+---------+---------+
| id  | text    | videoid |
+-----+---------+---------+
|   1 | person  |       1 |
|   2 | vehicle |       1 |
|   3 | animal  |       1 |
|   4 | person  |       2 |
|   5 | vehicle |       2 |
```

How to select `videoid` that have 3 labels (person, vehicle and animal)?
In our case, it's just first `videoid` = 1, because `videoid` = 2 have not enough labels, just 2 (person and vehicle)

Comment: `GROUP BY id HAVING COUNT(*)=3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could aggregation count(distinct(name),  group by ad use having for filter the result

if you need  3 distinct text

```
 select videoid 
 from my_table 
 group by videoid
 having count( distinct(text)) = 3
```

or this if you accept also repeated  text

```
 select videoid 
 from my_table 
 group by videoid
 having count( *) = 3
```